# Best method for clearing temp upload folder

Tags: php, mysql, apache, upload, cron

On one of my current projects, I am allowing users to upload images and set them as profile pictures.

The image initially will be stored in a temporary folder until the user crops & saves, or cancels the upload. Of course, there will be cases where they won't actually hit the cancel button. So I have to go through the temp folder and remove images not used after `x` minutes.

I can think of one way to do this, which would store the image data in `MySQL`, but I would rather just keep everything on `Apache` - though I'm not sure what language I'd use to actually perform the search and delete function.

Would this be a `cron` job?

Comment: Yes, a `cron` job would do just fine. Look at Linux' `find` command, it allows you to filter by modification/creation time and delete all in one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crop and save function is all JS I would recommend you to use the users local file and upload on "save".

JavaScript:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}    

// jQuery
$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});

// plain JS
document.getElementById('imgInp').onchange = function(){
      readURL(this);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/)

Credit to [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: there is now also a plain JS solution in the answer

Comment: Do you need some further help on this? :-)

Comment: No, I think I've got a handle on it now. Thanks!